# Create a collage of images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project and I got to a place where I decided to realized a collage.
I have done the collage already and it is here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1b8euyr0/)

But I would like to do the same thing without using the property `float` on the elements of `div1`.

If possible, I would like to use only the properties `right` and `left` on the element of `div1` without reducing the size of the elements of that div.

Sorry I'm not a native English speaker, I'm trying my best.

Comment: Fiddle link is not there.

Comment: Post has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, you would like to see something like this:

```css
body {
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div1{
  text-align:justify;
}

.div1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.div1 span img{
  width:45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">      
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/189/324?random=1" alt="rd1"/></span> 
  <span><img src="https://picsum.photos/189/324?random=2" alt="rd2"/></span>      
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/380/325?random=3" alt="rd3"/>
</div>
```

My comment: I have set an 'img' width value to 45%, but you could set it to any value which will be equal or less than 50%. By the way, I suggest you to use tag 'span' instead of 'p' because 'span' ,in my opinion, is more suitable for this purpose. If you will use my approach you will be able to add any number of images to parent 'div' tag. For example, if you will add any number of images and their total width will be equal or less than 100%, these images are will be placed evenly on row.

Answer (score 0):

you can use display: flex; like that you dont have to use float

```css
body {
 /* width: 520px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*.div1 p {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;

}*/

.div1  {
 display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.div2{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="div1">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/324/" alt=""/>
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/324/" alt=""/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/325/" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

you mean something like this?

```css
.div1 {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
.div2 {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
   <div class="div1">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/324/" alt=""/>
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/324/" alt=""/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/325/" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Nice, Thanks, It is working. Do you have any idea about how the same display can be made with the properties `right` `left` on the elements of `div1` ?

Comment: personally iI would do it with flexbox

Answer (score 0):

This is what you asked for. But I recommend not to go with this approach. Extending it will be a nightmare. If image sizes change then it will be impossible to fix with with just CSS.

```css
body {
  width: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div1{
  position:relative;
  height:324px;
}
.div1 p {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
 width:50%;
    position:absolute;
}

.div1 p:first-child {
  left:0px;
}

.div1 p:last-child {
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="div1">
   <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/324/" alt=""/></p>
   <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/189/324/" alt=""/></p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="div2">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/325/" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your help, my project is responsive, so for sure the size of the images will change based on the screen size. Can you help me fix it by keep this CSS code?

Comment: Why do you want to keep this particular code? As I told before you cannot make this code responsive just with CSS. You will need JS help, which is not a good practice.

Comment: The project I am working on, is a carousel made with the plugin named `owlcarousel`. That carousel have made does not display correctly the collage when I use [The method, I used for my collage](http://jsfiddle.net/1b8euyr0/) 
When I use `display:flex` or  `display:table`, I do have some issues on certain browsers.